# How can I have a loading image when a gridview is being loaded?

Tags: jquery, tabs, load, spinner, menuitem

I did some research, but I couldn't reach the answer for my problem. I want to have a loading image when I am clicking on a tab from my menu item. The following piece of code works great for specific events such as click() etc. (I have tried some other several examples), but it doesn't when my gridview is loading. I was wondering, is there any kind of event in jquery (I haven't find any) that reffers to when a control/entity STARTS to perform loading? I mean load(),onload(),ready() - all refer to the moment when the loading has finished.

Here is my code. Any help/suggestion is kindly appreciated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#spinner").bind("ajaxSend", function () {
            $(this).show();
        }).bind("ajaxError", function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSave,#btnOne,#btnTwo,#btnThree,#btnFour,#btnUndo').click(function () {
            //$("#spinner").append('<img id="img-spinner" src="Images/ajax-loader-test.gif" alt="Loading.." style="position: absolute; z-index: 200; left:50%; top:50%; " />');
            $('#spinner').show().fadeIn(20);
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the Asp code:

```
<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 150%; position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: Gray; left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0">
     <img id="img-spinner" src="Images/ajax-loader-test.gif" alt="Loading.."         style="position: absolute; z-index: 200; left: 50%; top: 50%;" />
</div>
```

Thank you, in advance, for your help.

EDIT: I have tried changing my function into:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#spinner").css.apply('display','none');
    });
```

and in my asp code I removed the display:none property, but it's still not working and I haven't got any clue what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add this code to your startup function:

```
$('body').ajaxStart(function() {
  $('#spinner').show();
});

$('body').ajaxComplete(function() {
  $('#spinner').hide();
});
```

That will show the div when the ajax call starts, and hide it when it completes.

To make the spinner show as the page loads initially, add this line to the document.ready:

```
$("#spinner").hide();
```

and take the "display: none;" off of the spinner div.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yup, it works like my previous piece of code (the spinner appears when I am clicking on a button (that has behind an action that takes some time to complete) etc., but it doesn't appear when I am clicking on a menuitem that takes me to a page containing a gridview with a lot of data (it takes about 3-4 seconds to load) :)

Comment: How is your gridview getting loaded? Can you add/show that code here or in a jsFiddle?

Comment: (I am not sure I got the question correctly) : My gridview is loaded when the page containing the gridview is loaded. The gridview is populated by simply binding the elements of a list to the columns of the grid. But I do have a huge amount of data, that's the reason why I need the spinner, to make my application somewhat more user-responsive.

Comment: You should show the spinner by default, and then hide it at document ready.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense the solution you've proposed, thank you, but I am clueless regarding what I am doing wrong (I have edited my initial post). Sorry for asking so many questions, I am very new at jquery.